# How do i make drawing stand out from background in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a small painter-like application. User has an ability to draw points on an uploaded image. It's done like so:

```
{
/...
QPainter paint(objectpix);

QPen PointPen (pointcolor[currentset-1]);
PointPen.setWidth(5);
QBrush PointBrush (pointcolor[setnumber-1],Qt::SolidPattern);
QPoint p1 = QPoint(mFirstX,mFirstY);

paint.setPen(PointPen);
paint.setBrush(PointBrush);
paint.drawEllipse(p1,2,2);

paint.end();
/...
}
```

*mFirstX,mFirstY* are coordinates of mouse click. The problem i'm facing is that color of point has to be really bright (*yellow(255,255,0)*,*red(255,0,0)*,etc) in order to stand out and not to make user screw his eyes searching for points drawn. I understand that it depends on an image on which user is drawing points. The problem is that my application is specific and most of the images do look like the one down bellow.
[image]
I want to use a lot of different colors for points and i want them to stand out from background. Any idea on possible solution?

Comment: In such cases where you aren't sure if your background color will create contrast you have to create your own contrast. What I mean is to draw points for instance as a small black circle on larger white circle. The white background forces the contrast to black point no matter the image background.

Comment: @Anže Your suggestion was useful to me, thank you

Comment: Maybe you can play with the [`setCompositionMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) to always have a Point with a visible color, perhaps the XOR mode ?